# How to properly nest select queries in postgresql? A specific (somewhat complex) example

Tags: postgresql, select, nested

I'd like some help with a query that I'm trying to build.

I have the following query that I'm building:

```sql
select sd.address,
       sd.colour_code,
       s.id as deactivated_id,
       s.type,
       'http://site/groups/' || c.group_id || '/user/' || c.subject_id as URL
from sensors s
   join contracts c on s.contract_id=c.id
   join sensordevices sd on sd.id=s.device_id
where s.begin_time is not null and 
      s.end_time is not null and 
      c.end_date is null and 
      not exists (select * from sensors sb
   where sb.begin_time is not null and --b properly entered
         sb.end_time is null and -- b active
         sb.contract_id=s.contract_id and
         s.type=sb.type and
         s.end_time<=sb.begin_time)
;
```

Which generates a table like this (without the barcode column which I would like to add):
[image]
On which I would like a barcode column, but the barcode is not in the database but a derived attribute.

In order to get barcodes I was given the following query:

```sql
SELECT
   ean || '' ||
   (
    10
    - 
    (
      (
        SELECT
          SUM(digit)
        FROM (
          SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() over () AS pos,
            digit
          FROM (
            SELECT
              REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(
                ean::TEXT,
                ''::TEXT
              )::INT AS digit
          ) AS split
        ) AS sub
        WHERE pos < LENGTH(ean::TEXT) 
        AND pos % 2 = LENGTH(ean::TEXT) % 2
      )
      +
      (
        SELECT
          SUM(digit * 3)
        FROM (
          SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() over () AS pos,
            digit
          FROM (
            SELECT
              REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(
                ean::TEXT,
                ''::TEXT
              )::INT AS digit
          ) AS split
        ) AS sub
        WHERE pos < LENGTH(ean::TEXT) 
        AND pos % 2 = (LENGTH(ean::TEXT) - 1) % 2
      )
    ) % 10 
  ) % 10 as barcode
FROM
(select '0' || sd.type || '00000' || sd.address as ean
    from sensors s
    join sensordevices sd on s.device_id = sd.id
    ) as ean;
```

Which returns a table with a single column, barcode.

So, my question is, how can I use the second query to select the barcode for the first statement?

What I tried was the following:

On my query after select I added `brc.barcode` and after from `(SECOND-LARGE-QUERY-HERE) brc`, but I got this error: `[53100] ERROR: could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp62390.6721": No space left on device` which I assume is because it's trying to temporarily save a list of every possible barcode before executing the query. I also tried adding some constraints inside the nested query, but I got another error there.

Could someone help me with the query?

Thank you very much for your time,
Bill

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, instead of the comma-separated syntax from 1989.

Comment: There you go, changed it!